# Records of Venus transits prior to 1761

Tags: history, venus, planetary-transits

Following the publication in 1716 of Edmond Halley's method to determine the solar parallax with the transit of Venus, many expeditions were launched to observe the 1761 transits. The following transits of 1769 and of the 19th century were also observed by many astronomers from all over the globe.

The telescope was already invented when the Venus transits of 1631 and 1639 occurred, so astronomers might have been able to observe them. Is there any record of such observations? Were any transits of Venus observed before the invention of the telescope?

Comment: Interesting Question. Did you already have a look at the Wikipedia article for the 1639 transit?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1639_transit_of_Venus

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_of_Venus#History_of_observation